# WKWebview doesn't load the next YouTube video when in the background

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, youtube, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView that loads a YouTube iFrame. This iFrame is passed a list of videos to play one after the other, as per [YouTube's API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions).

The WKWebview loads, buffers and plays the next video at the end of the current video automatically. This works fine when the app is in the foreground or when the screen is locked, but not when the home button is pressed.

When the home button is pressed and the video ends, the next video is loaded, placed in a buffering state but never plays. Trying to force the video to play doesn't work.

The exact sequence of playback statuses when the next video tries to load and play is:

- 0: Video ended
- -1: Video unstarted
- 3: Video buffering

The app has both the Audio background mode and Background Fetch background mode enabled, but it looks like the WKWebView gets suspended and prevents the iFrame from downloading and playing the next video data.

Any idea how to keep the iFrame alive in the background in order to start the next video?